# Select JSON value that match column id

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My data are of payments, amount, currency and a JSON object with the exchange rates for that particular date. This JSON contains ALL currencies and all exchange rates.

| Amount | Currency | Exchange rates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 666.00 | USD | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.07848,"Date":2018-10-21},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.106593,"Date":2018-10-21] |
| 123.00 | GBP | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.08239,"Date":2020-03-10},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.117549,"Date":2020-03-10}] |

How do I select just the correct rate in each object for each row?  The final goal is to have one column called "Amount in SEK".

I want a result that looks something like this:

| Amount | Currency | Exchange rates | Rate | Amount in SEK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 666.00 | USD | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.07848,"Date":2018-10-21},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.106593,"Date":2018-10-21}] | 0.106593 | 6248.07 |
| 123.00 | GBP | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.08239,"Date":2020-03-10},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.117549,"Date":2020-03-10}] | 0.08239 | 1492.90 |

Comment: As a side note: JSON support was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thats the thing, I've read so much on w3school ect but all I find is JSON_VALUE(Exchange rates,'$.Rate') but that just gives me null. It said at first before someone editied that I have never worked or came across JSON before, so I'm very lost. Sorry :(

Comment: You can use string search functions.

Comment: I've tried SQL string search functions like CHARINDEX(), but that is too slow for my big data. 

SQL question, how do I select the rate where ExchangeCurrency(JSON) match Currency(the column)?

Comment: I've tried JSON_VALUE(Exchange rates,'$.Rate') but that just gives me null and I don't know enough JSON/SQL to know how to the get the just one rate for the correct currency

Comment: The the rates in the JSON are the other way around (From SEK to USD) you have to divide  instead to get it from USD to SEK. That is just simple math. 666/0.106593=6248.07

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may parse the JSON data with `OPENJSON()`. The following statement is a possible solution to your problem (without rounding):

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (666.00, 'USD', '[{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.07848,"Date":"2018-10-21"},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.106593,"Date":"2018-10-21"}]'),
   (123.00, 'GBP', '[{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.08239,"Date":"2020-03-10"},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.117549,"Date":"2020-03-10"}]')
) v ([Amount], [Currency], [Exchange rates])
```

Statment:

```
SELECT 
   d.[Amount], d.[Currency], d.[Exchange rates], 
   j.[Rate], 
   CASE WHEN j.[Rate] > 0.0 THEN d.[Amount] / j.[Rate] END AS [Amount in SEK]
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.[Exchange rates]) WITH (
   ExchangeCurrency varchar(3) '$.ExchangeCurrency',
   Rate numeric(20, 5) '$.Rate'
) j 
WHERE d.Currency = j.ExchangeCurrency
```

Result:

| Amount | Currency | Exchange rates | Rate | Amount in SEK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 666.00 | USD | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.07848,"Date":"2018-10-21"},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.106593,"Date":"2018-10-21"}] | 0.10659 | 6248.24092316352378271882915 |
| 123.00 | GBP | [{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"GBP","Rate":0.08239,"Date":"2020-03-10"},{"BaseCurrency":"SEK","ExchangeCurrency":"USD","Rate":0.117549,"Date":"2020-03-10"}] | 0.08239 | 1492.89962374074523607233887 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, That seems to be what I'm looking for and I've done a bit of research and tried on my own code but it doesn't seem to work. I've also double-checked the server version. I'm running SQL Server 13.0.6300.2 which Google tells me is 2016.

I took my data and loaded it into a sample temp table.

```
SELECT top 100
s.STM_AMOUNT [Amount],
d.DIC_CODE [Currency],
REPLACE([CRR_CURRENCIES],'''','"') as [Exchange rates]
into #data
FROM database.SETTLEMENTS s
left join database.CURRENCIES c on c.crr_id = s.stm_crr_id 
left join database.DICTIONARIES d on d.dic_id = s.stm_cur_dic_id
```

Result

```
select * from #data
```

[image: Temp table #data]

I then do the code you suggested:

```
Select 
d.[Amount], d.[Currency], d.[Exchange rates], 
j.[Rate],
CASE WHEN j.[Rate] > 0.0 THEN d.[Amount] / j.[Rate] END AS [Amount in SEK]
from #data d

OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.[Exchange rates])
WITH(
ExchangeCurrency varchar(3) '$.ExchangeCurrency',
Rate numeric(20, 5) '$.Rate'
) j 
WHERE d.Currency = j.ExchangeCurrency
```

I have also tried "CROSS APPLY" but I get this error code:
*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.*

So I tried to add a semicolon ( ; ) in front of WITH but then everything after the colon gets error.

Comment: Then the database compatibility level is different. If possible, try to change it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll contact my IT department.